# Unity sprite rig affecting performance

Tags: unity, skeletal-animation

I created a simple sprite rig using the skinning editor provided by the new [2D Animation V2 package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.animation@2.1/manual/index.html). But it causes a huge FPS drop when added to the scene.

Methods such as SpriteSkin.LateUpdate generates significant amount of garbage as shown in the picture: See the spike shown on the CPU profiler when the rig is being enabled:

[image: unity sprite rig profiler]

The rig is not even animated.  I also checked the other sample rigs provided by Unity and they also performed in a similar fashion.

Is this normal? I'm targeting mobile, so anything that can be done to avoid or improve the situation will be helpful.

I'm using 2d-animation-v2 2.0.0-preview.2 in Unity 2018.3.8f

Comment: Check this out http://esotericsoftware.com/forum/Perfomance-issue-unity3d-4720

Comment: Preview packages are not quite ready for production use, so this might be an issue you want to raise with the developers themselves so they can improve the package prior to its non-preview release.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah it definitely is not production ready.